# SQL code to do a Union of data in MS-Access and keeping relevant information

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my Access table I need to sort.

[image: Table 1]

and I need it to look like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fMIg.png]

I know I could use this SQL code,

```
SELECT data1
FROM table
UNION
SELECT data2
FROM table
UNION
SELECT data3
FROM table;
```

to get it to list all the data columns in one column. What do I need to do so that I can retain the information for each piece of data. I'm really new to SQL and haven't used Access this advanced before so I really don't know what the terminology is to even google what I need.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this. Try read and understand the query:

```
SELECT item, type, description, data1 AS data
FROM table_name
WHERE Nz(data1, '') <> ''
UNION
SELECT item, type, description, data2 AS data
FROM table_name
WHERE Nz(data2,'') <> ''
UNION
SELECT item, type, description, data3 AS data
FROM table_name
WHERE Nz(data3,'') <> ''
ORDER BY item, type, description, data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
select item, type, description, data1 from [Table] where data1 Is not null
Union
select item, type, description, data2 from [Table] where data2 Is not null
Union
select item, type, description, data3 from [Table] where data3 Is not null
```

OR

```
select * from (

select item, type, description, data1 as data from [Table] 
Union
select item, type, description, data2 as data from [Table] 
Union
select item, type, description, data3 as data from [Table] )

where data is not null
```

Comment: Thank you. The top example code worked exactly as I needed. I even understand basically how it works too. I'll just keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with very slight changes with your code. Simply union the selection of main columns results.

```
SELECT item,type,discription 
FROM table
UNION
SELECT data1 as data
FROM table
UNION
SELECT data2
FROM table
UNION
SELECT data3
FROM table;
```

Comment: Union query must have same number of fields from each table